# table view datasource and delegate methods calling without loading data from web service?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my application I had make call Json function and table view delegate and datasource methods in view did load  but here without loading data from web service it is calling table view methods and inside it is crashing due to having no data from model can anyone help me how to resolve this and this is happening sometimes and sometimes it working properly ?

here is my view did load

```
let guestAddressURL = "http://magento.selldesk.io/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/\(guestkey!)/billing-address"
self.guestShippingaddressURL(guestAddressApi: guestAddressURL)
self.tableDetails.delegate = self
self.tableDetails.dataSource = self
self.tableDetails.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
self.tableDetails.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
self.tableDetails.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableDetails.estimatedRowHeight = 50
self.title = "Checkout"
```

here is my Json function

```
 func guestShippingaddressURL(guestAddressApi: String) {
        print(guestAddressApi)
        let url = URL(string: guestAddressApi)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
                    let obj = jsonObj["street"] as! [String]
                    for item in obj  {
                        self.street = item
                    }
                    print(obj)
                    print(self.street)
                    self.guestShippingAddressModel = GuestAddress.init(dict: jsonObj)
                    if self.street?.isEmpty == false  {
                        self.addressSelected = true
                        self.selected = false
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if self.street?.isEmpty == false{
            return 3
        }
        else {
            if ((addressSelected == true || checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true) && selected == false) {
                return 3
            }else {
                return 2
            }
        }
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        if ((addressSelected == true || checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true) && selected == false) {
            if (section == 0)
            {

                return 1
            }
            else if (section == 1)
            {
                return 1
            }
            else
            {
                return 1
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (section == 0)
            {
                return 1
            }
            else
            {
                return 1
            }
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if ((addressSelected == true || checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true) && selected == false){
            if (indexPath.section == 0) {
                return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            }
            else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
                return 62
            }
            else {
                if height == 0 {
                    return CGFloat(heightStart)
                }
                else{
                    return CGFloat(self.height)
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if (indexPath.section == 0){
                if self.street?.isEmpty == true{
                    return 50
                }else {
                    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
                }
            }
            else if (indexPath.section == 1){
                return 62
            }
            else {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)
    }
```

Comment: you should probably show part of your codes

Comment: I had added my code @koropok

Comment: show `numberOfRowsInSection` method

Comment: I added my code @Mr.Bista

Comment: also show your numberOfSections, numberOfRows, and cellForRowAtIndex Path.

Comment: and it is crashing in this first line `cell.nameLabel.text = "\((dict?.firstName)!) \((dict?.lastName)!)"
                cell.addressLabel.text = "\(self.street!) \((dict?.city)!) \((dict?.region)!) \((dict?.postCode)!)"
                cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = "\((dict?.telephone)!)"` in cell for row at index path method @ozzieozumo

Answer (score 1):

The tableview will start loading whether your JSON call has finished or not. This happens automatically after viewDidLoad finishes .. it doesn't wait for the reloadData() call in your completion handler.

So you need to setup your numberOfSections to return 0 until the data has been loaded.  This way, your table will be empty (and cellForRow will not even be called) until the completion handler puts the data in place and calls reloadData(). At which time, your numberOfSections will return non-zero and your data will be displayed.

Comment: but sometimes happening as expected sometimes only it's crashing and any specific reason for this ?

Comment: According to ur reason it should crash every time when I run application but sometimes working fine

Comment: Sometimes link may be called before the view did load state has been reached and some cases it doesnt finish the API call .. maybe.. anyway what @ozzie said is correct

Comment: yeah its a race condition and therefore fundamentally unpredictable.  Maybe it just worked some times, maybe you were setting breakpoints in the debugger that allowed time for the asynchronous task to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize all your variables used inside table view methods with some default values.

Like: `var street: String! = ""` , `var addressSelected: Bool! = false` etc.

Because even before the API is called, some of these values are `nil` or not set.

For `cell.nameLabel.text = "\((dict?.firstName)!) \`, you can `return 0` in `numberOfRows` method.

```
guard let _ =  dict {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: But I am returning data from model class at that time wat should I do

Comment: and it is crashing in this first line `cell.nameLabel.text = "\((dict?.firstName)!) \((dict?.lastName)!)"
                cell.addressLabel.text = "\(self.street!) \((dict?.city)!) \((dict?.region)!) \((dict?.postCode)!)"
                cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = "\((dict?.telephone)!)"`

Comment: In ur answer model class I need to assign to dict ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by set your Delegate and DataSource in web Service call Back.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableDetails.delegate = self
                    self.tableDetails.dataSource = self
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                }
```

hope it works.

Comment: I want to ask when we write self.tableDetails.delegate = self
                    self.tableDetails.dataSource = self in viewdidload , it calls delegate and data source methods ,it does not need to call reloadData () to call that methods  But  in web service call back why we need to call reloadData if we are setting delegate and datasource in DispatchQueue.main.async after web Service call Back? I am too facing this question.